# Let $a,b,c$ be positive reals. Prove that $ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ca(c+a)\geq \sum_{cyc} ab\sqrt {{a\over b}(c+a)(c+b)}$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b,c$ be positive reals. Prove that
>   $$ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ca(c+a)\geq \sum_{cyc} ab\sqrt {{a\over b}(c+a)(c+b)}$$

I have no clue and I am not good at inequalities. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First it's useful to expand
$$ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ca(c+a)=a^2b+b^2a+b^2c+c^2b+c^2a+a^2c$$
By Cauchy-Schwarz

$$\left(\sum_{cyc} ab\sqrt {{a\over b}(c+a)(c+b)}\right)^2\le\left( \sum_{cyc}a^2(c+b)\right)\left(\sum_{cyc}ab(c+a)\right)$$

now expand the RHS :
$$\left( ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ca(c+a) \right) \left(3abc+a^2b+b^2c+c^2a\right)$$

and recall that $3abc\le b^2a+c^2b+a^2c$ by AM-GM.
Hence we get
$$RHS\le \left( ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ca(c+a) \right)^2$$
and this is the desired inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $A = a^2b+b^2c+c^2a,B=ab^2+bc^2+ca^2$, we have $LHS=A+B$.

By AM-GM inequality $$ab\sqrt{{a\over b}(c+a)(c+b)} = \sqrt{a^2(b+c)\cdot ab(a+c)} \le \frac{a^2(b+c) + ab(a+c)}{2},$$
Thus 
$$RHS = \sum ab\sqrt{{a\over b}(c+a)(c+b)} \le \frac{1}{2}\sum [a^2(b+c) + ab(a+c)]=\frac{1}{2}(2A+B+3abc)\quad (1)$$
By AM-GM inequality again: $$B=ab^2+bc^2+ca^2 \ge 3\sqrt[3]{ab^2\cdot bc^2\cdot ca^2}=3abc\quad (2)$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have $$RHS \le \frac{1}{2}(2A+B+3abc) \le \frac{1}{2}(2A+B+B) = A+B = LHS,$$
QED.